# Pass data from NSOperation to next NSOperation

Tags: nsoperation

Is it possible to pass data from an NSOperation up the dependency chain to be used by the next NSOperation?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  The current `NSOperation` can access it's dependancies via the `dependencies` method:

```
NSArray *myDependancies = [self dependencies];
```

It can then access whatever properties you wish on the previous operations and pull out any data it requires.

In a recent project I found that I needed to pass data along so often that I created a subclass of NSOperation that automatically carried forward an `NSDictionary` of data from one operation to the next.

Answer (score 0):

I've read the [post](https://medium.com/@marcosantadev/4-ways-to-pass-data-between-operations-with-swift-2fa5b3a3d561) where you can pass data between operations.

Also raywenderlich book [Concurrency by Tutorials](https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/concurrency-by-tutorials) shows that you can pass data from dependecies like this:

```
let dependencyImage = dependencies
.compactMap { ($0 as? ImageDataProvider)?.image } .first
```