# How to do async task in non-concurrent custom nsoperation

Tags: ios, iphone

Maybe I let `NSOperation` to play a wrong role in non-concurrent job. My requirement is , I want to do a lot of async jobs, but I want them to be completed in order. When task1 is finished after the async callback, task2 can be take into work now. And I make all the task a `NSOperation`. However, `NSOperation` is used to multiple thread programming most time. Is my choice wrong. But it  remind me to think more about the `NSOperation` in this case, we can't manage manually the `isFinished` and `isExecute` in a sync block since the operation have been release in non-concurrent nsoperation,it means i couldnot use the powerful operation queue to automatically manage the task.Any idea?Thanks for your answer..

edit with code :

```
-(void)main {
    [super main];
    self.isOperationExcuting = YES;
    self.isOperationFinished = NO;
    WEAKSELF
    [self query:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
        //I set my custom property, but it do not cause my NSOperation to be finished
        weakSelf.isOperationFinished = YES;
        weakSelf.isOperationExcuting = NO;
    }];
}
-(void)query:(void (^)(NSArray *array, NSError *error))block {
    BmobQuery *query = [BmobQuery queryWithClassName:@"Room"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:block];
}
-(BOOL)isFinished {
    return self.isOperationFinished;
}
- (BOOL)isExecuting {
    return self.isOperationExcuting;
}
- (void)start {
    [super start];
    NSLog(@"start");
}
- (void)cancel {
    [super cancel];
    NSLog(@"cancel");
}
```

Comment: Think what your looking for is a `NSOperationQueue`, with `maxConcurrentOperationCount` set to one.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make all added operations serial by setting `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to `1`.

```
NSOperationQueue* queue = [[ NSOperationQueue alloc ] init];
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

[queue addOperation:operation1];
[queue addOperation:operation2];
[queue addOperation:operation3];
```

### NSOperationQueue

> The [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/) class regulates the execution of a set of
>   NSOperation objects. After being added to a queue, an operation
>   remains in that queue until it is explicitly canceled or finishes
>   executing its task.

Comment: My aim is : `[operation1 completionBlock:^(){ 
                   [operation2 completionBlock:^(){ 
                   [operation3 completionBlock:^(){ 
                   }];
                   }]`;
                   }];

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to chain operations in their completion handlers?

Comment: yeah... I have to start a operation in the previous operation's completion handlers.. thus I can do the job serially. is  the NSOperation improper?

Comment: `NSOperation` is proper, but instead of starting operations in completions handlers create a `NSOperationQueue`  and add your operations there. When you set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to `1` your operations will be run serially one after another as you want it.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, use queue can call the operation to start..But my operations have influence each other, In operation1' completion handler , it will return a BOOL value that is needed to operation2.For example, I want to pause the current song, then play a new song. If I take to pause operation and play operation into the queue, I cannot control them , and there exist one situation that my pause operation may failed, but it will play two song together..I need to know the pause operation is successful that I excute play operation..

Comment: Alright, now I get it. You can achieve this with creating dependancies between operations. There is `addDependency:` method of `NSOperation`. I would also subclass `NSOperation` and add a dictionary property for passing data between operations. Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402283/pass-data-from-nsoperation-to-next-nsoperation

Comment: thanks for your understand.. Now a new problem, dependency is good choice, but operaion2 will be excute when operation1's 'finished = YES', however If I use custom property, I have no idea to let operation1 finished when the async task in main function is finished. I have posted my code..

Comment: Sroka thanks for your patient answer, I have found the way, I can use kvo or notification in the async completion handler to finish operation1, and operation2 depend on operation1, thus they are excuted one by one!